# Binding of child control in treeview Item in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeviewitem

I have a treeview created using HierarchicalDataTemplate and binded using custom class. In treeview child items, i have checkbox, textblock and image. What i want is whenever checkbox is checked manually on UI, i want my image to change to right sign. 
I am not able to figure out how do i do this. Below is the XAML.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Repayment.TreeViewCustom"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidColorBrush1" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidColorBrush2" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidColorBrush3" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidColorBrush4" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidColorBrush5" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidColorBrush6" />

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="HeaderTextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SolidColorBrush4}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 5 10 5"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Century Gothic"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="ChildTextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SolidColorBrush3}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 5 10 5"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Century Gothic"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TreeView" x:Key="BackgroundTreeView">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SolidColorBrush1}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisualStyte}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <BulletDecorator>
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          MinHeight="30" MinWidth="30" ShowGridLines="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Border Name="MainBorder"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.RowSpan="9"
                                CornerRadius="4"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                Background="Transparent" />
                                <!--Transparent-->

                                <Border Name="InnerBorder"
                                Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                                Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="#808080" />
                                <!--#808080-->

                                <Path Name="InnerPath"
                              Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                              Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                              Data="M31,5 L19.5,5 19.5,19.5 34.5,19.5 34.5,11.75"
                              Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#808080"/>

                                <Path Name="CheckMark"
                              Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                              Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                              Opacity="0"
                              Data="M9.07743946676476E-09,4.31805768640244L4.68740335877841,8.86361158398516C4.68740335877841,8.86361158398516,16.3281249985376,-2.42451336648723,16.3281249985376,-2.42451336648723L14.0622100581796,-4.77304938341948 4.68740335877846,4.31805791992662 2.22656251699567,1.93164208562579z"
                              Fill="#3babe3" 
                              Stretch="Fill"
                              Stroke="#3babe3" />

                                <Path Name="InderminateMark"
                              Grid.Column="3"
                              Grid.Row="4"
                              Data="M0,4 L1,5 5,1 4,0"
                              Opacity="0"
                              Stretch="Fill"
                              StrokeThickness="0"
                              Fill="#808080" />
                            </Grid>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" >
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="InderminateMark" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,4,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </BulletDecorator>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="MainBorder" Property="Background" Value="#81d2eb" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Fill" Value="#cccccc" />
                            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Stroke" Value="#cccccc" />
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerPath" Property="Stroke" Value="#cccccc" />
                            <Setter TargetName="InderminateMark" Property="Fill" Value="#cccccc" />
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#cccccc" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView MinWidth="200" Name ="tvMain" TreeViewItem.Selected="tvMain_Selected" Style="{DynamicResource BackgroundTreeView}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding ChildStep}">
                <Border MinWidth="270" Height="26" Background="{DynamicResource SolidColorBrush2}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SolidColorBrush1}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Margin="2" Padding="2">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource HeaderTextBlock}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding GrandChildStep}">
                        <Border Width="250"  Background="{DynamicResource SolidColorBrush1}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SolidColorBrush2}"  CornerRadius="2" Margin="1" >
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="26"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="26"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCheckBoxChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle}" Grid.Column="0" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2"  Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{DynamicResource ChildTextBlock}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

                                <!--<Rectangle Name ="rct" Width="20" Fill="{Binding Path=Color}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2"></Rectangle>-->
                                <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2"></Image>

                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Width="200"  Background="LightBlue" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1" >
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="26"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Margin="2"  Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                                        <Rectangle Width="20" Fill="DarkOrchid" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2"></Rectangle>

                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a multibinding converter that takes a collection of objects and returns a value based on those objects. Here is an example;

```
 public class CheckedAndImageURLMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
 {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var checkboxIsChecked = (bool?)values[0];

        ImageSource newImageURL = ...;

        var imageURL = (ImageSource)values[1];

        if (checkboxIsChecked == true)
        {
            return newImageURL;
        }
        return imageURL;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In this example you get one image source if the checkbox is checked and another if not, this probably isn't exactly what you want (and I've not included a value for newImageSource) but hopefully you'll be able to adapt this to your needs.

Next you'll need to add a reference to it in your xaml. Something like this;

```
    <Window.Resources>
        ...
        <local:CheckedAndImageURLMultiValueConverter x:Key="AndImageUrlMultiValueConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Finally you'll have to replace your image xaml to make use of the multibinding with something like this;

```
            <Image Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2">
            <Image.Source>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AndImageUrlMultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="IsCheckBoxChecked" />
                    <Binding Path="ImageURL" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
```

Since you are using a converter you can be quite flexible with what you bind to, just caste the object values back to their original types in the multiConverter, do what ever logic you need and then return the value based on this.

Be careful with the order your bindings appear in the xaml, they need to match the order of the object[] values in the multiConverter.

U do not have to restrict yourself to just two bindings. The multiconverter lets you bind to more.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Glad you got things working. if you feel it is the answer could you mark it as the answer. Thanks.